# snoopy rsyslog output file rule

Tags: logging, rsyslog

I'm just setting up [snoopy logger](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopylogger/) on my personal machine to archive commands I've run.

I'm attempting to setup an rsyslog rule to move its messages from `/var/log/auth.log` to `/var/log/snoopy.log`

I've tried a few different rsyslog rules to move the output, but after resetting the rsyslog service it's still logging to `auth.log`

`~$ cat /etc/rsyslog.d/snoopy.conf`

```
#if $programname == 'snoopy' then /var/log/snoopy.log
#& ~
:programname, isequal, "snoopy" /var/log/snoopy.log
```

Could it be that the rule in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`

`auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log`

Is overriding any rule I specify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I renamed the file such that it was loaded earlier than the auth rule, and added `& ~` to stop messages that match this rule being used in other rules.

`~$ cat /etc/rsyslog.d/10-snoopy.conf`

```
:programname, isequal, "snoopy" /var/log/snoopy.log
& ~
```